# How can I create a forest plot with normal distributions instead of lines?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a forest plot with normal distributions (or normal-looking distributions) that overlay the lines in a normal forest plot.  You can see in the (poorly drawn) image below what I'm looking for: the lines with the dots in the middle are what a forest plot would normally look like, while the blue curves I drew on would be the distributions.

[image]

I'm not 100% sure where to start, to be honest.  I know how to make a forest plot, and I know how to make a normal distribution, and I know enough about ggplot to be fairly sure that this is possible, but I don't think I understand it nearly well enough to know where to begin.

This is the code I have for the forest plot.

```r
label <- paste0("X", 1:6)
mean  <- c(1.29,0.76,2.43,1.68,1.22,1.7) 
lower <- c(0.84,0.50,1.58,1.1,0.8,1.11)
upper <- c(1.95,1.16,3.67,2.54,1.85,2.56)

df <- data.frame(label, mean, lower, upper)

# reverses the factor level ordering for labels after coord_flip()
df$label <- factor(df$label, levels=rev(df$label))

library(ggplot2)
fp <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=label, y=mean, ymin=lower, ymax=upper)) +
  geom_pointrange() + geom_density() +
  geom_hline(yintercept=1, lty=2) +  # add a dotted line at x=1 after flip
  # flip coordinates (puts labels on y axis)
  xlab("Label") + ylab("Mean (95% CI)") +
  theme_bw() # use a white background
fp
```

I need to figure out some way to add a generic normal distribution to the right side of each one of the lines.

I've tried simply adding a

```r
 + stat_function(fun = dnorm, n = 101, args = list(mean = 0, sd = 1))
```

To the end of the ggplot, but it just adds a curved line to the bottom of the graph.  I'm sorry if I'm asking for help without trying out--I just don't know enough about ggplot to know where to start.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at `geom_violin`.

Comment: Related: https://solomonkurz.netlify.com/post/make-rotated-gaussians-kruschke-style/. Also related: `tidybayes::geom_halfeyeh`.

Comment: Thanks both of you--these were super helpful resources.  I think I have pieces I need to solve the problem. Thank you!